# ngSanitize : badparse for <style> <!--\n--> </style> gives bad parse error angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ngsanitize

I get a badparse error trying to sanitize

`<style> <!--\n--> </style>` gives bad parse error angularjs. I use ngSanitize in my module to sanitize. I am able to parse most HTML content well but this fails.

Is there a special reason why this string fails?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {     
    $scope.style = $sce.trustAsHtml(
   `<script>
      alert("Some bad");
    <\/script>
    <style>
        .green{
            background-color:green
        }
    </style>`);      
}])
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-bind-html='style'></div>
    <div class='green'>Green</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: What if there is a script tag in the string passed for trustAsHtml? Will that be executed? I dont want to execute any script. If possible, I would like to escape the script.

Comment: If you don't want to execute script, simply don't to insert it into your page.

Comment: Unfortunately, the content is user input. So I cannot rely on that.

Comment: You can try updated answer, `<script>` body is not invoked.